# Is there a neater way of traversing metric object lookups for PrometheusExporter in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, performance

I'm building a script for exporting Performance Monitor metrics to Prometheus using the module [PS Gallery - PrometheusExporter](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PrometheusExporter) specifying the metrics to use in a json.

Since the Prometheus-format isn't compatible with the names of the Windows Performance metrics, I need to convert the names using a translation table.

The issue I'm facing is when using "get all instances" `*`. Since I'm lazy, I prefer to write more code than translation tables :)
But the lookup using code gets a little messy :/
So I need help clarifying/simplifying the traversal code in the collector function so that it is easily understood when I read it in a couple of months ;)

I don't really like for-loops, but I don't think I can get rid of the index number since I need to do some look ups...
(maybe a hast table would be a better option?)
`for ($i=0; $i -lt $PerfCounters.Count; $i++)`
and one obvious issue is; if the available resources is changed without restarting the script, the lookup will be offset.

counters.base.json

```
[
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
    "MultiValue": false,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "CPU_Total",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Total CPU load in percent of all processors combined.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": "80"
  },

  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Avg_Bytes_Read",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Average number of bytes transfered from the disk during read operations.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Avg. Disk Bytes/Write",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Avg_Bytes_Write",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Average number of bytes transfered to the disk during write operations.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_sec_per_Read",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Average time, in seconds, of a read of data from the disk.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_sec_per_Write",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Average time, in seconds, of a write of data to the disk.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Disk Write Bytes/sec",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Write_Bytes_per_sec",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Rate at which bytes are transferred to the disk during write operations.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Disk Read Bytes/sec",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Read_Bytes_per_sec",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Rate at which bytes are transferred from the disk during read operations.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Disk Writes/sec",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_IOPS_Write",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Rate of write operations on the disk.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Disk Reads/sec",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_IOPS_Read",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Rate of read operations on the disk.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\% Disk Time",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Idle_Time_Percent",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Percentage of elapsed time that the selected disk drive was busy servicing read or write requests.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\% Free Space",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Free_Space_Percent",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Percentage of total usable space on the selected logical disk drive that was free.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\LogicalDisk(*)\\Free Megabytes",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Disk_Free_Space_Mbytes",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Unallocated space, in megabytes, on the disk drive in megabytes.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },

  {
    "CounterName" : "\\Memory\\Available Mbytes",
    "MultiValue": false,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Memory_Free_Mbytes",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "Amount of physical memory, in Megabytes, immediately available for allocation to a process or for system use.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes in Use",
    "MultiValue": false,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Memory_Commited_in_Use_Percent",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "The ratio of Memory\\Committed Bytes to the Memory\\Commit Limit. Committed memory is the physical memory in use for which space has been reserved in the paging file should it need to be written to disk.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  },
  
  {
    "CounterName" : "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Total/sec",
    "MultiValue": true,
    "MetricDescriptorName" : "Network_Bytes_per_sec",
    "MetricType": "gauge",
    "MetricHelp": "The rate at which bytes are sent and received over each network adapter, including framing characters.",
    "Label": null,
    "ThresHold": null
  }
  
]
```

New-PromethuesCollector

```
Import-Module PrometheusExporter

$Global:MetricCounters = Get-Content .\counters.base.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$InitialPerfCounters = (Get-Counter $MetricCounters.CounterName).CounterSamples

[array]$Global:MetricDescriptors = $null
foreach ($Counter in $InitialPerfCounters) {

    $Metric = $MetricCounters | where {
        $Counter.Path -like ('*' + $_.CounterName)
    }

    if ($Counter.InstanceName) {
        $MetricDescriptor = New-MetricDescriptor `
            -Name $Metric.MetricDescriptorName `
            -Type $Metric.MetricType `
            -Help $Metric.MetricHelp `
            -Labels 'Instance'
    } else {
        $MetricDescriptor = New-MetricDescriptor `
            -Name $Metric.MetricDescriptorName `
            -Type $Metric.MetricType `
            -Help $Metric.MetricHelp
    }

    $Global:MetricDescriptors += $MetricDescriptor
}

function collector {
    $PerfCounters = (Get-Counter $MetricCounters.CounterName).CounterSamples

    [array]$Metrics = $null
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $PerfCounters.Count; $i++) {
        if ($PerfCounters[$i].InstanceName) {
            $Metric = New-Metric `
                -MetricDesc $MetricDescriptors[$i] `
                -Value $PerfCounters[$i].CookedValue `
                -Labels ($PerfCounters[$i].InstanceName -split ' ' -replace ':','' | select -first 1)
        } else {
            $Metric = New-Metric `
                -MetricDesc $MetricDescriptors[$i] `
                -Value $PerfCounters[$i].CookedValue
        }
        
        $Metrics += $Metric
    }

    $Metrics

}

$PerformanceExporter = New-PrometheusExporter -Port 9700
Register-Collector -Exporter $PerformanceExporter -Collector $Function:collector
$PerformanceExporter.Start()
```

In accordance with the creators ReadMe at [GitHub - jobec/powershell-prom-client](https://github.com/jobec/powershell-prom-client), you of course need to allow network traffic at port TCP 9700 before verifying the page in a web browser (or allowing [Prometheus scraping](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#configure-prometheus-to-monitor-the-sample-targets)).

```
New-NetFirewallRule `
  -DisplayName 'Prometheus Exporter' `
  -Direction Inbound `
  -Action Allow `
  -Protocol TCP `
  -LocalPort 9700
```

Any suggestion about how to better go about the lookups in the metrics traversal?